# Как вызвать функцию класса из другого файла на python

Tags: python

У меня есть файл parser.py

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart


class Currency:
    url = 'юрл для сокращения'
    headers = {
        'юзер агент'}
    diferent = 1
    compare_currency = 0

 # init
    def __init__(self):
        self.compare_currency = float(self.get_currency())

# get currency bitcoin
    def get_currency(self):
        full_page = requests.get(self.url, headers=self.headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(full_page.content, 'html.parser')
        convert = soup.findAll(
            "span", {"class": "DFlfde SwHCTb"})
        return (convert[0].text).replace(",", "")

# compare and conclusion
    def check_currency(self):
        price = float(self.get_currency())
        if price >= self.compare_currency + self.diferent:
            print("Цена биткоина выросла, можно отдыхать.")
            self.send_mail()
        elif price <= self.compare_currency - self.diferent:

            print("Цена упала надо что-то делать!")
            self.send_mail()
        print("Сейчас курс биткоина= " + str(price))
        time.sleep(3)
        self.check_currency()
```

и пустой файл bot.py. Так вот я не понимаю как вызвать функцию check_currency через файл bot.py. Попытался сделать так

```
import parser
s = Currency() 
s.check_currency()
```

но выдаёт ошибку NameError: name 'Currency' is not defined

Comment: Про это в каждом учебнике написано. С чем именно проблемы?

Comment: Я уже 1 час ищу и не могу найти. Попытался сделать так
import parser 
s = Currency()
s.check_currency()
но выдаёт ошибку NameError: name 'Currency' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import parser
s = parser.Currency()
```

Comment: выдаёт ошибку s = parser.Currency() AttributeError: module 'parser' has no attribute 'Currency'

Comment: 1. Оба файла должны быть сохранены в одной папке. 2. В питоне уже есть модуль parser и у вас импортируется именно он. Чтобы избегать таких проблем, не нужно называть свои файлы так как названы другие модули.

Comment: Спасибо большое.